# Как в регулярных выражениях задать обязательную последовательность?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Как в js задать обязательную последовательность символов?
Для примера - "**К**" после которой идет "**5**" после которой идет "*****" после которой идет "**?**". Вот как выбрать последовательность из выделенных символов?

Comment: не понятный вопрос, вы хотите что-то вроде такого? /(K5\\*\?)/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто экранируйе метасимволы

```
K5\*\?
```

Comment: @ua6xh, Спасибо! Оказалось, что я не в том направлении задал вопрос :) Сейчас переспрошу.